# Removing & adding strings from a vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm new to C++ and I was just wondering how would I go about removing and adding strings from a vector. I have tried several implementations and the program does not seem to work has intended.

```
//allows the user to list thier top 10 video games
cout << "Please list your Top 10 favourite video games below.\n";
string gameTitle;
vector<string> gameList(10);
cin >> gameTitle;
gameList.insert(gameList.begin(), gameTitle);

//prints out the game list
vector<string>::iterator iterGameList;
cout << "Your Top 10 video games are:\n";
for (iterGameList = gameList.begin(); iterGameList != gameList.end() ++iterGameList)
{
    cout << *iterGameList << endl;
}

//allows the use to remove a game title from the list
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
P.S. Would I have to pass find() to erase() via an iterator.

Comment: _"and the program does not seem to work has intended."_ What's actually intended? You have to [explain more](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28253921/edit) please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By far the most common way to add items to a `vector` is with `push_back`, something like:

```
vector<string> gameList;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    std::string game;

    std::cin >> game;
    gameList.push_back(game);
}
```

To remove an item you use `erase`. For example, to remove all the items currently in your vector, you could use:

```
gameList.erase(gameList.begin(), gameList.end());
```

...though erasing all the contents is a common enough operation that there's a `clear()` to do exactly that.

Comment: Thanks push_back() works a lot better than trying to use insert() since I have to use it with an iterator which caused runtime errors to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `gameList.insert(gameList.begin(), gameTitle);`

use `gameList.push_back(gameTitle);`

Check out the article for information on push_back:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/